# Authenticator Presenter not showing up and Logging in

Tags: android, xamarin, google-drive-api

I'm using a sample Google Drive API snippet to connect to Google Drive and upload files using this repo https://github.com/stevenchang0529/XamarinGoogleDriveRest/blob/master/XamarinGoogleDriveRest/XamarinGoogleDriveRest/ViewModels/MainViewModel.cs .

I'm trying to implement in in this way.

```
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
             this.clientId, 
             string.Empty, 
             scope,
             new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth"),
             new Uri(redirectUrl),
             new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"),
             isUsingNativeUI: true);
            AuthenticatorHelper.OAuth2Authenticator = auth;

            try
            {
                var presenter = new OAuthLoginPresenter();
                //Is this supposed to show the presenter as well?
                //presenter.Login isn't loggin in and redirecting me to the login page
                presenter.Login(auth);
                System.Console.WriteLine("post login");
```

When this class is execute it makes its way down to presenter.Login and then it throws an exception. I'm doing it this way since I wasn't able to figure out how to bind the ICommand that I declared

`public ICommand OnGoogleDrive { get; set; }` 
Which was use to bind to a button in the sample demonstration of this code.

I'm unsure as to why it isn't working and my only idea is that my redirectUrl isn't set up properly but it wouldn't explain why I'm getting this in my logs.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.OAuthLoginPresenter.Login (Xamarin.Auth.Authenticator authenticator) [0x00012] in <3887a0d7d292416b83829cf88b593985>:0 
  at <path-cut-out>GoogleDriveApiHelper.cs:79
```

I'm also wondering if the login presenter is supposed to show up when `var presenter = new OAuthLoginPresenter();` is executed.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.